# Strip to remainder as whole number in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to basically be able to use the remainder as a whole number. 
So I may have a problem that is 277/10 = 27.7 So my remainder is .7 , I want to be left with only 7. 
I need to be able to take any remainder and subtract it from 10. 
So if my answer has a remainder of .7 I need to be able to do 10-7=3
If my answer has a remainder of .4 I need to be able to do 10-4=6 and so on.

I can not use RIGHT(A1,1) because it is a remainder so right goes to the end of the remainder which could be .699999999995 and it returns 5.

So I thought about trying to strip it somehow but have not been able to come up with anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want (bit of a strange request) but perhaps:

```
=10-INT(10*MOD(A1,1))
```

Assumes the division takes place in ColumnA.

Another possibility along the lines you were considering:

```
=10-RIGHT(ROUNDDOWN(10*A1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the remainder of 277/10, just use the MOD function to get your answer of 7 directly.

```
=MOD(277,10)
```

The full answer to your problem, with the subtraction from 10, is:

```
=10-MOD(277,10)
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of that in the first place. But it works well.The other way I found that works also is =MOD(ROUND(A1*10,0),10) but using your suggestion is much cleaner. Thanks Again.

Comment: No problem. Can you please mark an answer as correct using the green tick to close the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both of you, both of those answers got me exactly where I needed. 
Also just in case, another way I was shown to do it that works as well is:

=MOD(ROUND(A1*10,0),10) But doing it this way I had then do a second formula to subtract from 10.

And Pnuts, I needed this because I was finishing a check digit calculator using the Mod 10 function. And to get to the mod 10 check digit you have to take 10 minus whatever the remainder of your answer is.

Thanks again to both of you for the help.